# How to perform sort inside map in angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, sorting, observable, angular7

I have the following code where I have observable for which the data is assigned through map,but my problem is I want the field 'sortOrder' in my array to be sorted.

```
  this.overviewEnabledCards$ = this.store.pipe(
  select(overviewCardsQuery.getEnabledOverviewCards),
  map((tiles) =>
    tiles.map((tile) => {
      const { component, colSpan } = 
       config.TILE_CONFIG_MAP.hasOwnProperty(tile.cardInformation.code) &&
      config.TILE_CONFIG_MAP[tile.cardInformation.code];
      return {
        ...tile,
        tileConfig: { component, colSpan }
      };
    })
  ));


  <dashboard *ngIf="overviewEnabledCards.length > 0; else noOverviewEnabledCards" class=" vdl-row">
  <ui-tile-outlet *ngFor="let tile of overviewEnabledCards" [tile]="tile"></ui-tile-outlet>
</dashboard>
```

I want `map(tiles) ==` to be returned with the field 'sortOrder' value sorted.Can any one please suggest me help.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just insert a sort function:

```
this.overviewEnabledCards$ = this.store.pipe(
    select(overviewCardsQuery.getEnabledOverviewCards),
    map((tiles) => {
        const sortedTiles = tiles.sort((a,b) => {
            return a.sortOrder < b.sortOrder ? -1 : 1;
        });
        return sortedTiles.map((tile) => {
          const { component, colSpan } = 
           config.TILE_CONFIG_MAP.hasOwnProperty(tile.cardInformation.code) &&
           config.TILE_CONFIG_MAP[tile.cardInformation.code];
           return {
             ...tile,
             tileConfig: { component, colSpan }
          };
        })
      ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
this.overviewEnabledCards$ = this.store.pipe(
  select(overviewCardsQuery.getEnabledOverviewCards),
  map((tiles) =>
    tiles.map((tile,i) => {
      const { component, colSpan } = 
       config.TILE_CONFIG_MAP.hasOwnProperty(tile.cardInformation.code) &&
      config.TILE_CONFIG_MAP[tile.cardInformation.code];
      tile.sortOrder = i
      return {
        ...tile,
        tileConfig: { component, colSpan }
      };
    })
  ));
```

I have added index in your 'sortOrder' field you can add any other values if you want.